No aspect ratio selector in a custom block
I added the aspectRatio prop to the block.json file in a custom block that renders a grid of posts of a specific type:
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "my/custom-post-grid",
    "title": "Custom Post Grid",
    "description": "Display a grid of custom posts.",
    "textdomain": "mydomain",
    "category": "media",
    "attributes": {
        "category": {
            "type": "integer",
            "default": 0
        },
        "columns": {
            "type": "integer",
            "default": 3
        },
        "gap": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "10px"
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "dimensions": {
            "aspectRatio": true
        },
        "spacing": {
            "margin": true,
            "padding": true
        },
        "typography": {
            "fontSize": true,
            "__experimentalFontFamily": true
        }
    },
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}

But, I can't see the aspect ratio selector in the block sidebar:

What am I doing wrong?

Per the developer handbook:

This value signals that a block supports some of the CSS style properties related to dimensions. When it does, the block editor will show UI controls for the user to set their values if the theme declares support.

So in your theme you'll need to declare support either by setting appearanceTools to true in theme.json or the legacy way using add_theme_support( 'appearance-tools' ) in functions.php.
